# Rails: Adding text to a route's URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

Is it possible to append text to a route's URL, so instead of, say,

```
http://site/page/2
```

it comes out

```
http://site/page/2-cool-stuff-here
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid

Answer (score 3):

Since you appear to be okay with keeping the object's `id` in the url, you can override `to_param` like so:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    "#{id} #{name}".parameterize
  end
end
```

which would return `.../articles/1-[article name]` (As pointed out by the [FriendlyId RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) mentioned by @Benjamin Tan).

If you desire more functionality than just that, you should check out the FriendlyId gem (see the RailsCast link above).